# props is undefined inside React component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to clone my Main component's prop to all it's children. I'm using cloneElement but I get an error stating "props is undefined".

It seem's others are having the same issue (https://github.com/wesbos/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files/issues/6)

This is the code for my main component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './Nav';


const Main = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
      <Nav />
      {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props, children: props.children.props.children })}
    </div>
    )
  }
});

export default Main;
```

Here are my dependency versions:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.6",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bulma": "0.0.18",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "shuffle-array": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set the `children` property of your main components `props.children` to the childrens own `children` property, which frankly makes no sense. Also you're calling `props` directly instead of `this.props` which is probably why it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give your cloned the props like this

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
```

Take into account that cloneElement is only working if you give ONE node to main children. If many do a loop like explained in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html)